# How can I run a git bash script from python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, git-bash

I want to use git bash `pdftotext` command from a python script. I have tried `pypdf`, `pdfminer` and `tika` libraries, but none of them maintain the structure of the pdf file the way I need. I tried the line below, I am not getting any error but no output file as well.

```
os.system("start \"\" \"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe\" --login pdftotext -table '%s' '%s'" % (input, output))
```

Comment: You probably just want to run `pdftotext` - you don't need a bash shell to do this.

Comment: This is on Windows not Unix. 'pdftotext' is not recognized. Unless if there is a way I am unaware of?

Comment: Running git bash on Windows via Python seems tricky to do, have you tried the Python library `tabula`, using the `.read_pdf`? It's good for [reading tables from PDFs](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py).

Comment: I know it's on Windows. Git bash still runs Windows binaries. You just need to find out where pdftotext is installed.